# C# Visual Studio Screen size

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013,
I'm making WIndows phone 8.1 ultimate app.
I'm using 4,7 inch screen(In emulator), but when i added my app to my phone everethink looks different, smaller.How i can make for app auto size?
So that the entire application would have on the entire screen, not just to the part.

**Edit:**
I know bacground image its now that the best, but its only for test to see how can look page totaly.
4,7 inch screen: [Image_one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Csg.png)
6 inch screen: [Image_Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hui4I.png)
Different is TextBlock positions.....
This is my XAML:

```
   <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
    <Grid.Background>
        <!--fona attēls -->
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/b2.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>

    <TextBlock
        Margin="215,555,0,0" 
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        Text="Exit" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        FontSize="35"
        FontWeight="Medium" 
        PointerPressed="TextBlock_PointerPressed_4"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        />

    <TextBlock
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Margin="215,471,0,0"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        Text="About us"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        FontSize="35" 
        FontWeight="Medium" PointerPressed="TextBlock_PointerPressed_5"
        />

    <TextBlock 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Margin="216,429,0,0" 
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        Text="Settings"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        FontSize="35"
        PointerPressed="TextBlock_PointerPressed_1"
        FontWeight="Medium"
        />

    <TextBlock
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Margin="216,387,0,0"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        Text="Rules"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        FontSize="35"
        PointerPressed="TextBlock_PointerPressed_3" 
        FontWeight="Medium"
        />

    <TextBlock
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Margin="216,345,0,0" 
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        Text="New Game" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        FontSize="35" 
        PointerPressed="TextBlock_PointerPressed" 
        FontWeight="Medium"
        />


    <TextBlock
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Margin="216,513,0,0"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        Text="Video"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        FontSize="35" 
        PointerPressed="TextBlock_PointerPressed_2" 
        FontWeight="Medium"
        />

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided any XAML code but I will assume that your problem are fixed sizes of UI elements.

Don't create your user interface (XAML) with fixed width values, try to use `HorizontalAlignment=Stretch` where possible without specifying Width. This way your layout will always stretch to whole screen width on every device or emulator.

**After edit:**

The problem was that you specified a fixed margin from the left, which was always the same on bigger screens.
If you want your menu to always be on the bottom right then use this XAML:

```
   <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.Background>
            <!--fona attēls -->
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/b2.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <StackPanel
            Margin="32"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock
                FontSize="35"
                FontWeight="Medium"
                Text="Exit"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />

            <TextBlock
                FontSize="35"
                Text="About us"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />

            <TextBlock
                FontSize="35"
                FontWeight="Medium"
                Text="Settings"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />

            <TextBlock
                FontSize="35"
                FontWeight="Medium"
                Text="Rules"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />

            <TextBlock
                FontSize="35"
                FontWeight="Medium"
                Text="New Game"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />


            <TextBlock
                FontSize="35"
                FontWeight="Medium"
                Text="Video"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Good Idea, but this is how my problem looks:
1) This look in 4.7 inch screen:
[link](http://i.imgur.com/LSQePhf.png)
2)This look is in 6 inch screen:[link](http://i.imgur.com/7cTRLOd.png)
  See difference?Any idea?

Comment: You did not provide link for 6 inch screen

Comment: One thing I notice is that your background image has very small resolution. Because of that the image is blurry on the bigger screen. But can you please edit your question and provide some XAML or code so I can help you out.

Comment: @user5261457 use grid rows and colums and 0 (0!) margin & position. Also the background might be copyrighted, be careful.

Comment: @ardaozkal Do you mean somethink like this? [link](http://i.imgur.com/ozUFNwF.png)

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @user5261457 yes, but add gridrows first.

Comment: This is not needed in your case because the XAML will be much less readable, but will do the same thing.